# Header height in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, content-management-system

I have been trying to figure out how to change the header height in one of the Wordpress themes.

Here is the demo: http://demo.rescuethemes.com/gateway/style-guide/

So far I have only found this rule in style.css on line 287:

```
.bg-image {
  height: 210px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However, there is something else that overrides this because if I delete height completely, the header still remains the same height. Any ideas?

Comment: The height is caused by the padding on `.site-branding` plus the height of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The height is caused by the contents of the `div`. Set `height` to a value of your choice to override this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want since you are indeed, able to control the height of the header with that rule you provided. You said you removed it, so perhaps you want the header to have no height? That can be solved with

```
.bg-image { 
  height: 0;
 }
```

If you want to know why when you remove the rule, there's still a height in it, there is a logo image inside it with a height of auto, plus an element with the class of `.site-branding` giving padding to the logo. They take over when their parent element has no defined height. So if you remove the parent's rule, play with these two other elements.

```
.site-branding {
  padding: ...
}

.logo {
  height: ...
}
```

My advice, is that you learn the role of all elements involved in the header, and use your browser's code inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the bg-image values, as well as played with site-branging and logo elements, as suggested above!

Thanks